# Does a phantom type have the same alignment as the original one?

Tags: c++, struct, types, language-lawyer, memory-alignment

Consider the following struct that contains some environment values:

```
struct environment_values {
  uint16_t humidity;
  uint16_t temperature;
  uint16_t charging;
};
```

I would like to add some additional information to those values with a phantom type* and make their types distinct at the same time:

```
template <typename T, typename P>
struct Tagged {
    T value;
};

// Actual implementation will contain some more features
struct Celsius{};
struct Power{};
struct Percent{};

struct Environment {
  Tagged<uint16_t,Percent> humidity;
  Tagged<uint16_t,Celsius> temperature;
  Tagged<uint16_t,Power>   charging;
};
```

Is the memory-layout of `Environment` the same as `environment_values`? Does this also hold for mixed type layouts, e.g.:

```
struct foo {
    uint16_t value1;
    uint8_t  value2;
    uint64_t value3;
}

struct Foo {
    Tagged<uint16_t, Foo>  Value1;
    Tagged<uint8_t , Bar>  Value2;
    Tagged<uint64_t, Quux> Value3;
}
```

For all types I've tried so far, the following assertions held:

```
template <typename T, typename P = int>
constexpr void check() {
    static_assert(alignof(T) == alignof(Tagged<T,P>), "alignment differs");
    static_assert(sizeof(T)  == sizeof(Tagged<T,P>),  "size differs");
}

// check<uint16_t>(), check<uint32_t>(), check<char>() …
```

Since the size of the tagged and untagged variants is also the same, I *guess* the answer should be yes, but I would like to have some certainty.

<sup>* I have no idea how those tagged values are called in C++. "Strongly typed typedefs"? I've taken the name from Haskell.</sup>

Comment: Well, [basic.align] has *An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value*, so this is all implementation defined.  I would expect this to work for any sane compiler and if you worried you could just assert that your assumptions are correct and if they ever fail it will fire.

Comment: There is a guarantee that layout-compatible types have the same alignment ([basic.compound]/3), but I don't see anything saying that `struct { T m; }` and `T` are layout-compatible.

Comment: *Cue Star Wars theme*

Comment: Doing this. As long as you're on Itanium ABI & use for aggregates, you're fine.

Comment: What exactly do you feel is missing from the answers provided that motivated a bounty?  So I know what to focus on.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? I've successfully created taggings by declaring (not defining) mem fns like Foo is(Field<0>); and then using ctor reflection to associate T Foo::is(Field<i>) with the fields.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity exactly what you've commented on gsamaras' answer. That was the missing part. I think it's just fair that you get the bounty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Standard mentions in [[basic.align]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align):

> Object types have alignment requirements (3.9.1, 3.9.2) which place
>   restrictions on the addresses at which an object of that type may be
>   allocated. **An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value**
>   representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which
>   a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an alignment
>   requirement on every object of that type; stricter alignment can be
>   requested using the alignment specifier (7.6.2).

Moreover, [[basic.compound]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#3), mentions:

> The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined.
>   Pointers to **layout-compatible types shall have the same value
>   representation and alignment requirements** (6.11). [Note: Pointers to
>   over-aligned types (6.11) have no special representation, but their
>   range of valid values is restricted by the extended alignment
>   requirement].

As a result, there is a guarantee that layout-compatible types have the same alignment.

`struct { T m; }` and `T` are not layout-compatible.

As pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332326/are-structs-of-variables-of-the-same-type-layout-compatible-with-a-struct-contai/45332881#45332881), in order for two elements to be layout compatible then they both have to be standard-layout types, and their non-static data members must occur with the same types and in the same order.

`struct { T m; }` contains just a `T`, but `T` is a `T` so it cannot contain a `T` as its first non-static data member.

Comment: `struct { T m; }` and `T` are not layout-compatible.  In order to be layout compatible then they both have to be standard-layout types, and their non-static data members must occur with the same types and in the same order.  `T` might not be standard layout.  `T` might not even be a class.  But even if `T` does meet these requirements, `struct { T m; }` contains just a `T`, but `T` is a `T` so it cannot contain a `T` as its first non-static data member.

Answer (score 7):

According to the letter of the law, size and alignment of types is implementation-defined and the standard gives you few if any guarantees about what `sizeof` and `alignof` will return.

```
template <typename T, typename P>
struct Tagged {
    T value;
};
```

*In theory*, the compiler is permitted to add padding to the end of this struct, which would obviously alter the size and probably the alignment as well. In practise, the only time I could envisage this happening is if `T` was given some sort of compiler-specific "packed" attribute, but `Tagged` was not (but even then, [GCC seems to work okay](https://godbolt.org/g/UHE7kh)).

In any case, I'd say it would be a good idea to add some static asserts to ensure that the compiler is being sensible -- which is exactly what you've done :).

Comment: A compiler might choose to just use the same large alignment for all structs, just to keep it simple, adding padding accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by gsamaras, the standard guarantees the same alignment for *layout compatible* classes.

Unfortunately, `struct { T m; }` and `T` are not *layout compatible*.

In 12.2.21 the standard lays out the requirements for a *layout compatible* class:

> Two standard-layout struct (Clause 12) types are *layout-compatible classes* if their *common initial sequence* comprises all members and bit-fields of both classes (6.9).

And the definition of *common initial sequence* is in 12.2.20:

> The *common initial sequence* of two *standard-layout* struct (Clause 12) types is the longest sequence of non-static data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the structs, such that corresponding entities have *layout-compatible* types and either neither entity is a bit-field or both are bit-fields with the same width. [Example:
>   `struct A { int a; char b; };`
>   `struct B { const int b1; volatile char b2; };`
>   `struct C { int c; unsigned : 0; char b; };`
>   `struct D { int d; char b : 4; };`
>   `struct E { unsigned int e; char b; };`
>   The *common initial sequence* of `A` and `B` comprises all members of either class. The *common initial sequence* of `A` and `C` and of `A` and `D` comprises the first member in each case. The *common initial sequence* of `A` and `E` is empty.
>   — end example]

So from this we can make the following important observations:

1. Layout compatibility is limited strictly to standard layout classes. (Or enums use the same underlying type or the trivial case when `T` and `T2` are literally the exact same type.  See 6.9.11.) In the general case, `T` is not a standard layout class.  In fact, `T` is not even a class in your example (it is a `uint16_t`, believe it or not, this matters according to the standard.)*
2. Even if `T` is guaranteed to be a standard layout class, `struct { T m; }` does not have a common initial sequence with `T`.  The sequence of `struct { T m; }` begins with `T`, whereas the sequence of `T` begins with whatever `T`'s non-static data members are.  This is actually strictly guaranteed not to be a `T` as a class cannot contain itself by value.

Therefore, the guarantee cannot be held by the letter of the standard.  You should continue to perform the `static_assert`ions to ensure your compiler is behaving in the fashion you expect.

* See most questions on union type punning.

Comment: Your name is... familiar. Aren't you a game developer? Starbound? Either way, I was looking for an answer that brought the layout into the game; a final **"no"** to the original question, that states that the static assertions are necessary (and maybe not even enough, since the types are not layout compatible)

Comment: Yes, bravo Zeta for giving OmnipotentEntity the bounty, +1.

Comment: Zeta, I am.  I'm touched you recognized me :)  That being said, all is not lost, because even though it's not guaranteed by the standard, it might be guaranteed by your compiler as most of the stuff revolving around alignment is implementation defined.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity can you have a look at [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48058545/1139697)?

Comment: @Zeta, you're correct that this is undefined behavior, and for the right reasons.