# Are there any guarantees for unions that contain a wrapped type and the type itself?

Tags: c++, struct, types, language-lawyer, unions

Can I put a `T` and a wrapped `T` in an `union` and inspect them as I like?

```
union Example {
    T value;
    struct Wrapped { 
       T wrapped;
    } wrapper;
};
```

```
// for simplicity T = int

Example ex;
ex.value = 12;
cout << ex.wrapper.wrapped; // ?
```

The C++11 standards only guarantee save inspection of the common initial sequence, but `value` isn't a `struct`. I *guess* the answer is **no**, since [wrapped types aren't even guaranteed to be memory compatible to their unwrapped counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425250/does-a-phantom-type-have-the-same-alignment-as-the-original-one) and [accessing inactive members is only well-defined on common initial sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is undefined behavior.

[[class.mem]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-21) gives us:

> The *common initial sequence* of two standard-layout struct types is the longest sequence of non-static data members and bit-fields in declaration order, starting with the first such entity in each of the structs, such that corresponding entities have layout-compatible types and either neither entity is a bit-field or both are bit-fields with the same width. [...]
>
> In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type `T1`, it is permitted to read a non-static data member `m` of another union member of struct type `T2` provided m is part of the common initial sequence of `T1` and `T2`; the behavior is as if the corresponding member of `T1` were nominated.

If `T` isn't a standard layout struct type, this is clearly undefined behavior. (Note that `int` is not a standard layout struct type, as it's not a class type at all).

But even for standard layout struct types, what constitutes a "common initial sequence" is based strictly on *non-static data members*. That is, `T` and `struct { T val; }` do not have a common initial sequence - there are no data members in common at all!

Hence, here:

```
template <typename T>
union Example {
    T value;
    struct Wrapped { 
       T wrapped;
    } wrapper;
};


Example<int> ex;
ex.value = 12;
cout << ex.wrapper.wrapped; // (*)
```

you're accessing an inactive member of the union. That's undefined.

Answer (score -1):

Union behavior is undefined when accessing a member that wasn't the last one written to.  So no, you can't depend on this behavior.

It's identical in principle to the idea of having a union to extract specific bytes from an integer; but with additional risk of the fact that you're now depending on the compiler not adding any padding in your struct.  See [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior) for more details.

Comment: Your first paragraph doesn't hold for common initial sequences. Also, I've linked the Q&A already in my question.

Comment: I think the answer from @Steeve and forcing the alignment with union alignas(sizeof(T)) Example { T value; struct Wrapped { T wrapped; } wrapper };  should work

Comment: @Zeta I'm pretty sure that it does hold.  Yes, you may have linked the question, but re-read it  (note that the answer there has both C11 & C++11)  You'll see that it states that `value of at most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time` - and the concept of a trap representation has been removed.

Comment: @UKMonkey No idea :/. Every answer on this question has at least one downvote (including the deleted one).

Answer (score -1):

It should work because  both `Example` and `Wrapped` are *standard layout* classes, and C++14 standard has enough requirements to guarantee that in that case `value` and `wrapper.wrapped` are located at the same address. Draft n4296 says in 9.2 Class members [class.mem] §20:

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address
>   of its first non-static data member.

A note even says:

> [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct
>   object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. —end note ]

That means that you at least respect the *strict aliasing rule* from 3.10 Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval] §10

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined
>   
>   — the dynamic type of the object,
> ...
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic
>   data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>   or contained union),

So this is perfectly defined:

```
cout << *(&ex.wrapper.wrapped) << endl
```

because `&ex.wrapper.wrapped` is required to be the same as `&ex.value` and the pointed object has the correct type.
.
But as the standard is explicit only for *common subsequence*. So my understanding is `cout << ex.wrapper.wrapped << endl` invokes undefined behaviour, because of a note in 1.3.24 [defns.undefined] about 
undefined behavior
says (emphasize mine):

> Undefined behavior may be expected when this International Standard **omits any explicit definition** of
>   behavior...

TL/DR: I would bet a coin that most if not all common implementation will accept it, but because of the note from 1.3.24 [defns.undefined], I would never use that in production code but would use `*(&ex.wrapper.wrapped)` instead.

---

In the more recent draft n4659 for C++17, the relevant notion is *inter-convertibility* ([basic.compound] §4).

Comment: Uh, I wasn't aware of [defns.undefined]. Thanks for bringing that up. The wording in C+11's 9.2§20 is very similar, but explicitly mentions pointer: *"A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its
initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa"*. So you can cite n3337 if you want to include C++11 in your answer.

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer that has the right address and type, does not make the object it refers accessible.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Literaly: `reinterpret_cast<union_A*>(&union_A.member_a)->member_b` supposing that member_b is the active member, member_a does not need to be active.

Comment: @Oliv: That's the reason why I use a pointer. As `value` has just been assigned, it is the active member of the union. Because `value` and `wrapper.wrapped` have same address and same type, `&ex.wrapper.wrapped` is in fact a pointer to `ex.value` which is the valid member. That the reason why it can be dereferenced.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, In the standard, it is never said that a pointer with the right value and type is a *pointer to object* [basic.compound], and there are given many exemple where a pointer with the right address and type are invalid pointer. For exemple `int arr[10]{}; *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&arr)=1` is UB evenif the address of the array and the address of its first element are the same.

Comment: @Oliv [basic.compound] §3 contains explicitely: *If an object of type T is located at an address A, a pointer of type cv T\* whose value is the
address A is said to point to that object, **regardless of how the value was obtained**.*

Comment: @SergeBallesta Which version of the standard? i do not find it in the last one.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Found it, they have just removed this exact sentence in the C++17 standard! So until C++17 your answer is right for sure. If you could make a small edit (and maybe mention it) I could upvote again.

Comment: @Oliv n4296 for C++14. Same sentence in n3337 for C++11. In n4659 for C++17 the notion is the *inter-convertibility* of pointers in §4 of basic compound. A pointer to an array and a pointer to its first element are not inter-convertible because they have different types.

Comment: I admit the exemple is not perfect. Here a closer one: `unsigned char buffer[2*sizeof(int)]; auto p1=new(buffer) int{}; auto p2 = new(p1+1) int{}; *(p1+1)=10 //UB`, here `*(p1+1)` does not point to `*p2` even if `p1+1` has the right type and right address.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I have asked a question about that, I hope to get a clear answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062346/is-a-pointer-with-the-right-address-and-type-still-always-a-valid-pointer-since

Comment: You can't get around the lifetime rules that easily. There's a decent argument that simply writing `ex.wrapper.wrapped` is UB by omission because [expr.ref]/4.2 defines the behavior of the class member access expression only when the first expression (here, `ex.wrapper`) designates an object, but there's no living `Wrapped` object. Moreover, if `Wrapped` has a nontrivial constructor, then [class.cdtor]/1 makes that same expression explicitly UB.