# Using std::launder to "validate" non "pointer to object" pointer value since C++17

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, stdlaunder

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062531/5632316), since C++17, even if a pointer has the right address and the right type dereferencing it can cause *undefined behaviour*.

```
 alignas(int) unsigned char buffer[2*sizeof(int)];
 auto p1=new(buffer) int{};
 auto p2=new(p1+1) int{};
 *(p1+1)=10; // UB since c++17
```

The reason is that  the pointer value of `p1+1` is [*a pointer past-the-end of*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.compound#3.2) an object. Can this example be brought back to defined behavior using `std::launder`:

```
 *std::launder(p1+1)=10; // still UB?
```

Secondly, would it also be useful in this following case?

```
alignas(int) unsigned char buffer[3*sizeof(int)];
auto pi = new (buffer) int{};
auto pc = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(pi);//not a "pointer to" an element of buffer 
                                               //since buffer[0] and *pc 
                                               //are not pointer interconvertible
//pc+2*sizeof(int) would be UB
auto pc_valid = std::launder(pc) //pc_valid is a pointer to an element of buffer
auto pc_valid2 = pc_valid+2*sizeof(int); //not UB thanks to std::launder
auto pi2 = new (pc_valid2) int{};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. The bytes constituting the `int` object `p2`  points to are not [reachable](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ptr.launder#3.sentence-2) through `p1+1`.

---

The "reachable" rule basically means that `launder` doesn't allow you to access storage you can't legally access via the original pointer. Since an opaque function may `launder` pointers as much as it wants, permitting this kind of shenanigans would substantially inhibit escape analysis.

Comment: And for the second example, does it make sense?

Comment: Same answer. The remaining `2*sizeof(int)` bytes of the array is not reachable through `pi`.

Comment: TIL that cxxdraft-htmlgen creates links to individual sentences as well. Neat

Comment: @T.C.: I can certainly see the need to distinguish pointers which will never be used to derive outside objects from those that might, but a language which doesn't have any pointer types that can retain the ability to derive the addresses of outside objects is fundamentally weaker than one which does.

Comment: @T.C.: Further, what's often needed is not the ability to launder a pointer and have it be usable indefinitely, but rather the ability to create a pointer to an object which can access other objects but, for its lifetime, would be subject to limitations akin to C's `restrict`.  Essentially, the creation and destruction of such a pointer would act as sequencing barriers, but use of them would not.  Code which creates such pointers within a tight loop might perform badly, but being able to put barriers outside a loop may allow more efficient code than would otherwise be possible.

Comment: But in the second example, he only uses `std::launder` to get a pointer (`pc_valid`) to the first element of the buffer, isn't it valid?

Comment: @xskxzr No. See the linked definition of "reachable" and the *Requires:* clause.