# Is using 2 dimensional array as 1 dimensional array correct? May cause Undefined Behaviour or so?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is this code proper? Is using 2 dimensional array as 1 dimensional deprecated for some reason?

```
char tab1[3][3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       tab1[i][j] = (char)i;

printf("%c", ((char*)tab1)[3]); // == tab1[1][0]
```

Comment: @meaning-matters I believe the asker's question is "Is `arr2d[1][0]` the same spot as `arr1d[3]` if `arr1d` is `arr2d` flattened into 1 dimension via casting?". If this is the question, you have a bug in the code, Semi__. No, no bug in code. Apologies, Semi__, I misread.

Comment: Unless there's some special case I don't know about, this should work just fine, but I don't know if it's considered undefined behavior. Someone more knowledgeable than me on C specifications should answer this.

Comment: Semi__ asked the Q and then asked himself "_What do you mean_"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fine, if for no other reason, because `char` can alias all other types according to the standard. Also *multidimensional* arrays are allocated as a contiguous block so it is a one dimensional array in memory to begin with.

We know that `tab1` decays to a pointer to the first element of a contiguous multidimensional array (which is an array) and casting that *array* pointer to a `char*` (which can alias anything) must be fine.

If in doubt you could always do `&tab1[0][0]`. Again because we know the allocated memory is contiguous.

**EDIT**

If this was an *integer* array (`int tab1[3][3]`) then the story is a little different. To my understanding *before* `C++17` the standard says that a pointer to the correct object type is valid *regardless* of how it obtained its value. That means casting to `int*` should be fine because we know the address yielded by `tab1` is the same as the address of the first element.

However **after** `C++17` that guarantee has been removed so this cast is likely *undefined behavior*.

[See THIS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062346/is-a-pointer-with-the-right-address-and-type-still-always-a-valid-pointer-since) for more details.

For that reason I would *always* recommend using `&tab1[0][0]` which will *always* be valid.

Answer (score 0):

> Is using 2 dimensional array as 1 dimensional deprecated for some reason?

When you use `tab1` the way you have, it decays to a pointer of type `char (*)[3]` (a pointer to an array of 3 `char`s). It does not decay to `char*`.

You cannot use it as a `char*` without explicitly casting it.

> Re: Is this code proper?

It's well defined since, for `tab1` in your code, `&tab1`, `&tab1[0]`, and `&tab1[0][0]` point to the same location in memory even though they are all different types.

Comment: Well he did explicitly cast it, the question is if doing this [assuming the subsequent rows are contiguous in memory] is UB or not.

Comment: @R Sahu Yes, I know they point to the same location in memory, but wouldn't be using that sort of bad practice? Or could be wrong in any particular case?

Comment: @Semi__, it is poor practice but It is OK as long as you are mindful of the valid range of indices.