# std::launder use cases in C++20

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, stdlaunder

**[1]**

Are there any cases in which the addition of [p0593r6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html) into C++20 (*§ 6.7.2.11* Object model [[intro.object]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object)) made `std::launder` not necessary, where the same use case in C++17 required `std::launder`, or are they *completely orthogonal*?

---

**[2]**

The example in the spec for [[ptr::launder]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#6) is:

```
struct X { int n; };
const X *p = new const X{3};
const int a = p->n;
new (const_cast<X*>(p)) const X{5}; // p does not point to new object ([basic.life]) because its type is const
const int b = p->n;                 // undefined behavior
const int c = std::launder(p)->n;   // OK
```

Another example is given by @Nicol Bolas [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39382728/2085626), using a pointer that points to a valid storage but of a different type:

```
aligned_storage<sizeof(int), alignof(int)>::type data;
new(&data) int;
int *p = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<int*>(&data));
```

Are there other use cases, not related to allowing casting of two objects which are not [*transparently replaceable*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#def:transparently_replaceable), for using `std::launder`?

Specifically:

- Would *reinterpret_cast* from A* to B*, both are [*pointer-interconvertible*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:pointer-interconvertible), may require using `std::launder` in any case? (i.e. can two pointers be *pointer-interconvertible* and yet not be *transparently replaceable*? the spec didn't relate between these two terms).
- Does *reinterpret_cast* from [void*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#5) to T* require using `std::launder`?
- Does the following code below require use of `std::launder`? If so, under which case in the spec does it fall to require that?

A struct with reference member, inspired by [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-proposals/93ebFsxCjvQ/myxPG6o_9pkJ):

```
struct A {
    constexpr A(int &x) : ref(x) {}
    int &ref;
};

int main() {
    int n1 = 1, n2 = 2;
    A a { n1 };
    a.~A();
    new (&a) A {n2};
    a.ref = 3; // do we need to launder somebody here?
    std::cout << a.ref << ' ' << n1 << ' ' << n2 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before C++17, a pointer with a given address and type always **pointed to** an object of that type located at that address, provided that the code respects the rules of [basic.life]. (see: [Is a pointer with the right address and type still always a valid pointer since C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062346/is-a-pointer-with-the-right-address-and-type-still-always-a-valid-pointer-since)).

But in the C++17 standard added a new quality to a pointer value. This quality is not encode within the pointer type but qualifies directly the value, independently of the type (this is the case also of the traceability). It is described in [[basic.compound]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.compound#3.sentence-8)

> Every value of pointer type is one of the following:
>
> - a pointer to an object or function (the pointer is said to point to the object or function), or
> - a pointer past the end of an object ([expr.add]), or
> - the null pointer value for that type, or
>   an invalid pointer value.

This quality of a pointer value has its own semantic (transition rules), and for the case of `reinterpret_cast` it is described in the next paragraph:

> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a **pointer to one** from a **pointer to the other** via a reinterpret_­cast.

In [basic-life], we can find an other rule that describes how transitions this quality when an object storage is reused:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer **that pointed to the original object**, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, [...]

As you can see the quality "pointer to an object" is attached to a specific object.

That means that in the variation bellow of the first example you give, the `reinterpret_cast` does not allow us not to use the pointer optimization barrier:

```
struct X { int n; };
const X *p = new const X{3};
const int a = p->n;
new (const_cast<X*>(p)) const X{5}; // p does not point to new object ([basic.life]) because its type is const
const int b = *reinterpret_cast <int*> (p);                 // undefined behavior
const int c = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast <int*> (p));
```

A `reinterpret_cast` is not a pointer optimization barrier: `reinterpret_cast <int*>(p)` points to the member of the destroyed object.

An other way to conceive it is that the "pointer to" quality is conserved by `reinterpret_cast` as long as the object are pointer inter-convertible or if its casted to void and then back to a pointer inter-convertible type. (See [[exp.static_cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.static.cast#13.sentence-3)).  So `reinterpret_cast <int*>(reinterpret_cast <void*>(p))` still points to the destroyed object.

For the last example you gives, the name `a` refers to a non const complete object, so the original `a` is transparently replaceable by the new object.

---

For **the first question** you ask: "Are there any cases in which the addition of p0593r6 into C++20 (§ 6.7.2.11 Object model [intro.object]) made std::launder not necessary, where the same use case in C++17 required std::launder, or are they completely orthogonal?"

Honestly, I have not been able to find any cases that where std::launder could compensate implict-lifetime objects. But I found an example were implicit-lifetime object makes std::launder usefull:

```
  class my_buffer {
      alignas(int) std::byte buffer [2*sizeof(int)];
      
      int * begin(){
         //implictly created array of int inside the buffer
         //nevertheless to get a pointer to this array, 
         //std::launder is necessary as the buffer is not
         //pointer inconvertible with that array
         return *std::launder (reinterpret_cast <int(*)[2]>(&buffer));
         }
      create_int(std::size_t index, int value){
         new (begin()+index) auto{value};
         }
       };
```

Comment: _"As you can see the quality "pointer to an object" is attached to a specific object"_ This rule in [basic.life] existed before C++17. So this quality isn't new.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I agree with that.

Comment: Though the answer provides a mostly thorough explanation of the subject, it does not reference directly the specific questions.

Comment: @AmirKirsh You mean the first 2 questions, no?

Comment: There are a few questions that are not answered: are p0593 and std::launder orthogonal? can two pointers be pointer-interconvertible and yet not be transparently replaceable? does reinterpret_cast from void* to T* require using std::launder? are there use cases, not related to allowing casting of two objects which are not transparently replaceable, for using std::launder?

Comment: @AmirKirsh I added an answer for the first of those questions above. For the second question, Yes! two objects must have the same type to be transparently replaceable, this is not the case for pointer-interconvertible. Third question? Only if the pointer of type void* pointed to an object that is not pointer-interconvertible or not transparently-replaceble with the object of type T* that you intend to get a pointer to.

Comment: For the last question: usr launder only to get a pointer to an object that is within its lifetime from an object that is either not transparently-replaceable or not pointer-interconvertible with the object you try to get a pointer to. There are no other use cases.

Comment: Hm, your last example is similar to [P0593R6's third motivating example](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html#dynamic-construction-of-arrays) - and in contrast to your example it' begin method doesn't use `std::launder`. Also in contrast to your example it uses placement new.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Honestly, it is undoubtedly wrong. Whatsoever, after 3 month of posting bug reports to Clang and GCC, and considering it took 3 years to fix them, I don't think it is reasonable to use C++ to do low-level programming. You should consider Rust. C and C++ aliasing rules, and C++ lifetime rules, are an unrecoverable mistakes.